# Post page to display specific category

Tags: posts, categories

Here is the template code

```
<?php
/**
* The template used for Home page */
?>

<section id="mosaicPosts">
<!-- MosaicPost-->
<div id="mosaicTiles" class="clearfix">

<?php
    global $post;

    $numberposts = esc_attr( get_theme_mod( 'number_homeposts', '6' ) );

    $args = array(
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post__not_in'   => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ),
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'terms'    => array( 'post-format-image' ),
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'operator' => 'IN',
            ),
        ),
        'numberposts' => $numberposts
    );
    $home_posts = get_posts($args);
?>
<?php if( $home_posts ) { ?>

<?php
$num = 0;
foreach( $home_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>

<?php  if ( $num == 6 ){ $num = 1; } else { $num++; } ?>

<?php  if ( $num == 2 ){ $class = 'vertical'; } ?>
<?php  if ( $num == 3 || $num == 4 ){ $class = 'rectangle'; } ?>
<?php  if ( $num == 1 || $num == 5 ){ $class = 'big-square'; } ?>
<?php  if ( $num == 6 ){ $class = 'big-rectangle'; } ?>

<div class="box <?php echo $class; ?>">
    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/layout', 'tiles' ); ?>
</div>

    <?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<?php } // if( $home_posts ) ?>

</div><!-- #mosaicTiles -->
</section>

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home-top' ) ) { ?>
<section id="prebefore-home-widget">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home-top' ); ?>

</section>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home-above' ) ) { ?>
<section id="before-home-widget">

<div class="grid<?php $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets(); echo count($sidebars_widgets['home-above']); ?> clearfix">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home-above' ); ?>
</div>

</section>
<?php } ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/section', 'home-page' ); ?>

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'home-below' ) ) { ?>
<section id="after-home-widget">

<div class="grid<?php $sidebars_widgets = wp_get_sidebars_widgets(); echo count($sidebars_widgets['home-below']); ?> clearfix">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'home-below' ); ?>
</div>

</section>
<?php } ?>
```

I've tried using the get_ function but only seem to get 503 errors in return.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

At be top of your template code:

```
<?php
/**
* The template used for Home page
?>
```

You never closed the comment with a `*/` which is commenting out the rest of your code. It should look like this:

```
<?php
/**
* The template used for Home page */
?>
```

Comment: @MarioEspinoza Be sure to click the green checkmark next to my answer and upvote this to indicate that your question is solved.

Comment: that didnt solve my problem though, just the way it appeared on the site.

Comment: @MarioEspinoza I don't entirely understand your question other than missing the `*/` in your comment. Please update it to clarify what you want to do. Treat it as if we don't know anything and explain everything that is relevant so everyone can get a better idea on your current situation.